# Spring SOAP merging .xsd files

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, xsd

I have two .xsd files in my web service, I will write them down here, my goal is to have instead of two, one xsd file and still have the same functionality(so that I can have only one wsdl), I have tried to search here and in goolge for similar problems but could not find any, maybe i am writing the problem wrong :/

File 1 and 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.org.com/action" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.org.com/action" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="getActionRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Username" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="getActionResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:tns="http://www.org.com/validate" 
        targetNamespace="http://www.org.com/validate" elementFormDefault="qualified">

        <xs:element name="getValidateRequest">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Username" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:int"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="getValidateResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

    </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.org.com/action" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.org.com/action" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="getActionRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Username" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="getActionResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="getValidateRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="Username" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="getValidateResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: thank you, I start to implement it but how should I change some of the beans(i update my post)